# Power amplifier - why is NF decreasing with freq. and I-V curve doesn't attain saturation?

Tags: amplifier, noise

Attached are the schematic of a PA with some relevant technical data, and simulations I ran. I'd like to ask a few questions concerning my results. Hopefully one of you will be willing to provide some insight, for which I shall be very grateful.

1) In the attachment NF vs. freq. the NF is shown to be decreasing as freq. increases for \$2<freq.<3GHz\$. Why does the noise figure decrease with frequency in this frequency range? Is this a normal behavior? What are the possible reasons in any case?

2) Why are there such strong fluctuations in gain for \$7<Vgs<12V\$? Why isn't saturation attained for \$ Vgs>7V \$ (I-V curves)? What are the possible reasons for that (fluctuations and not attaining saturation) and how may I determine the actual cause?

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnl0K.jpg)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: There's so much white empty space to the right of the first images.

Comment: I don't know this FET at all, but the gain vs. Vgs plot makes me think I'd like to keep the gate voltage below 7 or so.

Comment: Please, can anyone try and explain to me why there appear to be such strong fluctuations in gain for Vgs>7 (temperature maybe?) and the possible reason for which the NF decreases as freq. increases? In the technical data sheet it is stated that the range for Vgs is -0.5<Vgs<12V. I'd be very thankful for some meaningful input.

Comment: How are you simulating this? Is your test circuit identical to the one supplied in the datasheet? Why is the decreasing NF over that range counter-intuitive to you?